# Javascript Array conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I was wondering how I could turn this:

```
var data = [  
     {id:1,option1:'short',option2:'red',option3:'gold'},  
     {id:2,option1:'short',option2:'red',option3:'silver'},   
     {id:3,option1:'short',option2:'blue',option3:'gold'},  
     {id:4,option1:'short',option2:'blue',option3:'silver'},  
     {id:5,option1:'long',option2:'red',option3:'gold'},  
     {id:6,option1:'long',option2:'red',option3:'silver'},   
     {id:7,option1:'long',option2:'blue',option3:'gold'},  
     {id:8,option1:'long',option2:'blue',option3:'silver'}]
```

Into something formatted like this using Jquery.

```
var new_data = {
            short:{
              red:{gold:1,silver:2},
              blue:{gold:3,silver:4}
            },
            long:{
              red:{gold:5,silver:6},
              blue:{gold:7,silver:8}
               }
       }
```

Comment: You can, you just have to sift through the data and create the object yourself. I'll make you a fiddle.

Comment: Question - are your input and output stuff objects that are already in memory, or just text? If they're objects, you can walk through the object using loops to reformat as you see fit.

Comment: @Sebastien Renauld If it is a string, he can use `parse()` to make it into an object

Comment: Doesn't look like it is a string. His example uses an array literal.

Comment: Sorry, I was responding to sebastien's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is easier than you might think. Try this:

```
function helper(obj,tree,value) {
    for( var i=0, l=tree.length; i<l-1; i++) {
        obj[tree[i]] = obj[tree[i]] || {};
        obj = obj[tree[i]];
    }
    obj[tree[i]] = value;
}
var new_data = {}, l = data.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    helper(new_data,[data[i].option1,data[i].option2,data[i].option3],data[i].id);
}
```

Comment: Nicely done, faster and better than my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This plain JS will do it:

```
var data = […];
var new_data = {};
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var o = new_data;
    for (var j=1; j<3; j++) {
        var prop = data[i]["option"+j];
        o = o[prop] || (o[prop] = {});
    }
    o[data[i]["option"+j]] = data[i].id;
}
```

But it looks easier to use that nested schema in the first place?

Comment: You solution doesn't provide the correct result, it only returns the silver counts.

Comment: @Jlange: If you're executing this in the console, you'll need to add an explicit `return JSON.stringify(new_data, null, 4)` of course (otherwise it will only print `8`, i.e. the last id)

Comment: No, I ran it in my fiddle, it doesn't return the proper data structure

Comment: @Jlange: [Better?](http://jsfiddle.net/9wTQf/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` like this:

```
var new_data = data.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    if (!res[obj.option1])
        res[obj.option1] = {};
    if (!res[obj.option1][obj.option2])
        res[obj.option1][obj.option2] = {};

    res[obj.option1][obj.option2][obj.option3] = obj.id;
    return res;
}, {});
```

---

or like this:

```
var new_data = data.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    var o = res;
    for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        o = (o[obj["option" + i]] = o[obj["option" + i]] || {});

    o[obj.option3] = obj.id;
    return res;
}, {});
```